# Python: Summarizing & Aggregating Groups and Sub-groups in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by, aggregate

I am trying to build a table that has groups that are divided by subgroups with count and average for each subgroup. For example, I want to convert the following data frame:

[image]

To a table that looks like this where the *interval* is a bigger group and columns *a thru i* become subgroups within the group with the corresponding subgroups' count and average in each cell:

[image]

I have tried this with no success:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) and tuples for aggregate functions with new columns names:

```
df1 = (df.melt('interval', var_name='source')
         .groupby(['interval','source'])['value']
         .agg([('cnt','count'), ('average','mean')])
         .reset_index())
print (df1.head())
  interval source  cnt  average
0        0      a    1      5.0
1        0      b    1      0.0
2        0      c    1      0.0
3        0      d    1      0.0
4        0      f    1      0.0
```

Comment: The result looks like it's counting items that fall into each interval only. How can you make it to count items that fall into both _interval_ and _source_?

Comment: @user9532692 - I am confused with output, can you explain row `6~9 a 2 7` from output? why `2`? why `7` ?

Comment: 2 is the count every item that falls in the interval 6~9 **AND** source a. 7 is the average of those two items that falls in the same group (interval 6~9 AND where source is a)

Answer (score 2):

Try.

```
df.groupby(['interval']).apply(lambda x : x.stack()
                                           .groupby(level=-1)
                                           .agg({'count', 'mean'}))
```

Use `groupby` with `apply` to apply a function for each group then `stack` and `groupby` again with `agg` to find `count` and `mean`.

Comment: I get an error message saying **TypeError: count() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given**

Comment: @user9532692 It worked fine for me. I'm not sure what happened. Can you try to use only `mean` or replace `count` with `size`?

Comment: I am still getting an error message saying **DataError: No numeric types to aggregate**. I wondered if it's because the data values are not in integer, but running *type(hh.iloc[1,1])* returns *numpy.int64*

Answer (score 0):

The following code solves the problem I asked for:

```
df.group(['interval'],,as_index=False).agg({
                                                'a':{"count":"mean"},
                                                'b':{"count":"mean"},
                                                'c':{"count":"mean"},
                                                'd':{"count":"mean"},
                                                'f':{"count":"mean"},
                                                'g':{"count":"mean"},
                                                'i':{"count":"mean"}
                                            })
```