# Python: Multiple Statistics per Group

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I am  trying to do multiple statistics per group. I can do count of each group but I can't figure out how to get the percentage of each group.

Here is what I have:

[image]

In my example, I forced the 881 for all rows to calculate the percent values, but I would like to replace 881 with something like *count of each final_stage* and calculate the percent of each final_stage.

Comment: please post a sample df and expected output df as text along with explaination, images cant be copied.

Comment: From [ask]: "_DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text._"

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need specify column after `groupby` and pass tuples with new columns names with aggregate functions:

```
df.groupby('final_stage')['d1'].agg([('ctn','size'), ('percent', lambda x: len(x)/ len(df))])
```

Or:

```
df1 = df.groupby('final_stage')['d1'].size().reset_index(name='ctn')
df1['percent'] =  df1['ctn'] / len(df)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your prompt response! I am struggling with another groupby statement as shown in the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55663359/python-summarizing-aggregating-groups-and-sub-groups-in-dataframe/55663833?noredirect=1#comment98022929_55663833). I greatly appreciate your help :)

Comment: @user9532692 - added solution